# React CRA Build Time Variable Issue - Multiple Entry Workaround

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use react and create-react-app to choose a build target based on an environment variable using a dynamic import. Here is what i'm trying to accomplish:

```
const BUILD_TARGETS : ITarget[] = [
  {
    name: "app",
    path: "./modules/app/Index",
  },
  {
    name: "admin",
    path: "./modules/admin/Index",
  },
];


// Determine which entry point to import
const target = BUILD_TARGETS.find(c=>process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_TARGET === c.name) as ITarget;

//Import the entry point and render it's default export
import(`${target.path}`).then(({ default: BuildTarget }) =>
  ReactDOM.render(
   
    <>
    <BuildTarget />
  
    </>
      ,
    document.getElementById("root")
  )
);
```

I've tried setting REACT_APP_BUILD_TARGET a number of ways as referenced here [CRA Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables), however, there seems to be some underlying issue where both modules are built and code from both modules are included in the final build assets. If I directly specify the module path like below, the correct module is built and code from the other is excluded:

```
    import("./modules/app/Index").then(({ default: BuildTarget }) =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    
    <>
    <BuildTarget />
  
    </>
      ,
    document.getElementById("root")
  )
);
```

Is there a limitation in CRA that prevents react-scripts from accessing an environment variable in the entry file?

Workaround:
This doesn't answer my question of why above is not working, but I've settled on a workaround. I'm scripting and copying over the entry file before running react-scripts start/build commands. In my case i'm executing a powershell script as follows:

```
"build-app": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./build.ps1 src\\app.index.tsx build",
"build-admin": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./build.ps1 src\\admin.index.tsx build",
"start-app": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./build.ps1 src\\app.index.tsx start",
"start-admin": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./build.ps1 src\\admin.index.tsx start"
```

build.ps1

```
$module=$args[0]
$script=$args[1]
Copy-Item $module -Destination "src/index.tsx"
npm run-script $script
```